# Redirect to a random url from a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have a json file full of links and i want to make a  random button to redirect to some of the links listed on that json file

json file example :

```
{"pages":[
      {
        "url": "https://www.google.com/"
       },
 {
        "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
       },
 {
        "url": "https://www.twitter.com/"
       },
 {
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/"
       },
  ]
}
```

Comment: show us what have you tried? post the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<button id="randomLinkButton">
Random Page
</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function getRandomUrl(){

  // define your source JSON data file URL
  var url = 'http://server/file',
        def = $.Deferred();

    $.getJSON( url ).done(function( data ){
    // received

    // get random index
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.pages.length);

    // resolve with random URL
    def.resolve( data.pages[ randomIndex ].url );

  }).fail( function( error ){

    // failed
    def.reject( error );
  });

  return def;
}

$(document).ready( function(){
  getRandomUrl().done(function(url){

    // button click code
    var buttonClickCode = "window.location.href = '" + url + "'";

    // button click handler
    $('#randomLinkButton').attr('onClick', buttonClickCode)

  }).fail(function(){

    // failed
  });

});
```

A better way to handle click handler for button shown in [JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uak94nz8/)

> Redirected page will be shown as blank in JsFiddle because of blocked

Comment: @H77 I have used your code for getting random URL from array, credit goes to you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to pick a random number between 0 and the array length. Then [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) to convert it to an integer.

This value can then be used as an index to pick a random object from the array.

Once you have that `location.href` or `location.replace()` can be used to redirect the page to the randomly picked url. Code example below:

```js
var json = {
  "pages": [{
      "url": "https://www.google.com/"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://www.twitter.com/"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/"
    },
  ]
};

var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * json.pages.length);
var url = json.pages[index].url;
console.log("Redirecting to: " + url);
location.href = url;
```

**Fetching from server json file:**

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $.getJSON("/index.json", function(json) {
    console.log("Data retrieved: " + json);
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * json.pages.length);
    var url = json.pages[index].url;
    console.log("Redirecting to: " + url);
    location.href = url;
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you, This is exactly what i've been looking for, could you please tell me how could i use it as a file instead? like var json = { urls.json }

Comment: i'm sorry i've tried like but it doesn't seem to work :        var json = $.getJSON( "/index.json", function() {
  console.log( "success" );
})


$('button').click(function() {

    
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * json.pages.length);
location.href = json.pages[index].url;

});

Comment: The data retrieved from getJSON can be read in the callback function. Check the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript Math.random() function with Math.floor() function to generate a random number between any range.

In your case it would be 0 to size of your array. Generate a random number using above functions and pick that index and redirect to that link on button click.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp